# How to interact with multiple tables in sql or codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I want to interact with 4 tables in codeigniter. I tried but gave no result. My tables look like :

```
----university----     ----------department----------    -------language--------
| id |  name     |     | id |         name          |    | id |    name        |
------------------     ----------------------------     -----------------------
| 1  | Oxford    |     | 1  | Computer Engineering  |    | 1  |  English       |
| 2  | Harvard   |     | 2  | International Affairs |    | 2  |  German        |
```

The rows  of these tables are just examples. My 4th table contains data about other tables.

```
  --------------------------result----------------------------
  | result_id | university_id | department_id | language_id  |
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  |    1      |    4          |       6       |      8       |
  |    2      |    4          |       7       |      4       |
```

I want to diplay  in same row university name, department name and  language at the same time which language id =2. I tried that code but it didn't any result :

```
$this->db->select('university.name,department.name,language.name' );
$this->db->from ( 'university' );
$this->db->from ( 'department' );
$this->db->from ( 'language' );
$this->db->join ( 'result', 'result.university_id = university.id', 'inner' );
$this->db->join ( 'result', 'result.department_id = department.id', 'inner' );
$this->db->join ( 'result', 'result.language_id   = language.id', 'inner'   );
$this->db->where( 'result.language_id', '2' );
$this->db->order_by( 'department.name', 'asc' );

$query = $this->db->get ();

return $query->result ();
```

Answer (score 1):

try to make from / join structure

```
$this->db->select('university.name,department.name,language.name' );
$this->db->from ( 'university' );
$this->db->join ( 'result', 'result.university_id = university.id', 'inner' );
$this->db->from ( 'department' );
$this->db->join ( 'result', 'result.department_id = department.id', 'inner' );
$this->db->from ( 'language' );
$this->db->join ( 'result', 'result.language_id   = language.id', 'inner'   );

$this->db->where( 'result.language_id', '2' );
$this->db->order_by( 'department.name', 'asc' );

$query = $this->db->get ();

return $query->result ();
```

If it does not work try to make 3 different queries and merge all!